# Cant access any data from Firebase Documents after calling collection in order to show it on screen

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a react native application and I am integrating google firebase into my project. I currently have the firestore database setup and linked to the application. It is even getting the documents when I make the query.

My simple issue is that I can not seem to be able to access the data in the firebase document in order to display it on screen.

What I want to do is grab the logged in users id which is working. I think want to go through each document in the collection and grab the `userId` which is store in the document. I want to see if the logged in `userId` and document `userId` are the same. If they are the same push the document data into an array that is set as a state and display it for the user.

here is the code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(auth.currentUser === null){
      navigation.navigate('LoginStack')
    }
    const collectionRef = collection(db, 'UserFavorites')
    getDocs(collectionRef)
      .then((snapshot) => {
        let properties = []
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(auth.currentUser.uid)
          console.log(doc.data())
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
      })
  }, [])
```

The second console log is where I want to display the userId from the document
`console.log(doc.data())`

--UPDATE--

console:

```
j4aeXJORvINA8m2bYpNGMcaUm9T2
Object {
  "address": "966 Palisades Beach Rd, Santa Monica, CA 90403",
  "bathrooms": 8,
  "bedrooms": 5,
  "contingentListingType": "FHA",
  "country": "USA",
  "currency": "USD",
  "dateSold": Object {
    "nanoseconds": 842000000,
    "seconds": 1658695140,
  },
  "daysOnZillow": 1,
  "hasImage": true,
  "imgSrc": "https://photos.zillowstatic.com/fp/64da6094eae05eba27184401e006ee69-p_e.jpg",
  "latitude": 34.01869,
  "listingStatus": "FOR_SALE",
  "livingArea": 7043,
  "longitude": -118.50533,
  "lotAreaUnit": "sqft",
  "lotAreaValue": 5466.78,
  "price": 25000000,
  "propertyType": "SINGLE_FAMILY",
  "userId": "j4aeXJORvINA8m2bYpNGMcaUm9T2",
  "zpid": "20485843",
}
```

Comment: can you provide what value are getting for the console.log?

Comment: I have add it to the original question @BhaveshDaswani

Comment: I want to just grab the userId from the object and not the entire object.. that is what I can not figure out how to do. @BhaveshDaswani